# How do I do a mask in Illustrator like Photoshop where both layers show?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, clipping-mask

For example, I want to draw a teal circle with part of an orange circle on it.

When I select them both and choose "make clipping mask", it gives me the correct orange part, but the teal part is now invisible:

[image]

Here is what happens in Photoshop and what I'm trying to achieve in Illustrator:

[image]

Comment: Shapebuilder would also be pretty simple for this task: [`Shapebuilder tool`](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html) - You can erase by holding down the `Alt` modifier.  — There's also the `Window > Pathfinder`, in which you could use the `Divide`. Hovering over the icons shows the names. It's the one at the bottom left. It's more destructive than using masks. Pathfinder is sorta like a cookie cutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the Clipping Mask is made

- Get the **Direct Selection Tool** and click on the mask edge to
  select it
- Fill it

[image: colored mask]

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. I don't supposed there's a setting anywhere that does that by default?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, the best way to work with Illustrator is not thinking in a Photoshop way and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever shape is used for the mask shape is automatically invisible

Clone the shape you want to use as your mask (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and then select all and make the mask.

Make sure that the **mask** shape is on top. clipping mask will follow whatever the top shape is.